# Compare if number (long) contains another number (also long)

Tags: python-2.7, iteration

I am looking for some solution how to compare one long number, if it contains another long number.
I have range of phone numbers, lets say for example:
Range starting from 2333222000 and ending 2333222999. Then I am iterating this range and trying to find out, if any of those numbers match for example: 233322211 - note that last number is missing, but for me it is still match.
My current code fails on error:

> "TypeError: argument of type 'long' is not iterable"

Here is my current solution:

```
print type(range_filter) #returns <type 'long'>
for i in range(long(range_from), long(range_to)):
   if range_filter in i:
      #Do something here if it matches
```

Comment: I would also note, that following code resolves error, but I am not sure, if it is best way how to do that - I mean mainly from performance point of view:
    if str(range_filter) in str(i):

Comment: Based on current answers, I am starting thinking, if some regex solution wouldn`t be a best option?

Comment: I wrote it under different answer, which is not here anymore (probably deleted). Current solution does not work with some phone numbers combinations leading to range overflow error. I am inserting into range_from and range_to international format phone numbers, which can be in case of Finland even 18 digits long...

Answer (score 0):

You could cast them to string and compare strings like this :

```
a = str(2333222000)
b = str(233322211)
c = str(2333222999)

if b > a and b < c:
    print "the number is in the range"
```

Comment: Your code is wrong. Try this `'10' > '2' and '10' < '100'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `range` then the stop value has to be the one after the last one you are interested in.

Your difficulty is that you are interested in whether `range_filter` is a *substring* of one of the numbers in the range. So you have to convert them both to strings first.

```
range_filter = 233322211
for num in range (2333222000 , 2333222999 +1):
    if str(range_filter) in str(num):
        print 'match for', range_filter, 'on',num
```

That gives

```
match for 233322211 on 2333222110
match for 233322211 on 2333222111
match for 233322211 on 2333222112
match for 233322211 on 2333222113
match for 233322211 on 2333222114
match for 233322211 on 2333222115
match for 233322211 on 2333222116
match for 233322211 on 2333222117
match for 233322211 on 2333222118
match for 233322211 on 2333222119
```

Put a `break` after the `print` if you are only interested in the first possible match. And if you don't consider 33322211 to match 2333222119 then instead of `in` use `.startswith()`.

```
if str(num).startswith(str(range_filter)):
```